# Haskell type error with forkFinally I just can't work out

Tags: multithreading, haskell, network-programming

Along with the error I'm having, any tips on how terrible what I'm doing is would be appreciated.

So I'll paste the code, it's a bit; but I think it's *mostly* correct, I just can't get forkFinally to type check...

The error is on the only line that calls forkFinally:

> ```
> Ambiguous type variable `e0' in the constraint:
>   (Exception e0) arising from a use of `forkFinally'
> Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
> In a stmt of a 'do' block:
>   t <- forkFinally (echoHandler a) (exitPool p)
> In the expression:
>   do { a <- accept s;
>        t <- forkFinally (echoHandler a) (exitPool p);
>        atomically
>        $ do { p' <- readTVar p;
>               writeTVar p (t : p') };
>        repeatAccept s p }
> In an equation for `repeatAccept':
>     repeatAccept s p
>       = do { a <- accept s;
>              t <- forkFinally (echoHandler a) (exitPool p);
>              atomically
>              $ do { p' <- readTVar p;
>                     .... };
>              .... } Failed, modules loaded: none.
> ```

Here's the code:

```
type ConnectionHandler = (Handle, HostName, PortNumber) -> IO ()
type Pool = TVar [ThreadId]

runConn = do
  s <- withSocketsDo (listenOn (PortNumber 1234))
  p <- atomically (newTVar ([]::[ThreadId]))
  t <- forkIO (repeatAccept s p)
  repeatUntilExit stdin stdout putChar ""
  p' <- atomically (readTVar p)
  mapM killThread (t:p')

repeatAccept s p = do
  a <- accept s
  t <- forkFinally (echoHandler a) (exitPool p) -- Error here, forkIO instead compiles fine.. (and I guess actually should work just fine too?)
  atomically $ do
    p' <- readTVar p
    writeTVar p (t:p')
  repeatAccept s p

exitPool :: Pool -> a -> IO ()
exitPool pool = \_ -> do
  tid <- myThreadId
  atomically $ do
    pool' <- readTVar pool
    writeTVar pool $ filter (/=tid) pool'
    return ()

echoHandler :: ConnectionHandler
echoHandler a@(hdl,_,_) = repeatUntilExit hdl hdl echoToHandleAndStdout ""
  where echoToHandleAndStdout x = hPutChar hdl x >> putChar x

repeatUntilExit :: Handle -> Handle -> (Char -> IO ()) -> [Char] -> IO ()
repeatUntilExit hIn hOut f "exit\n" = hPutStrLn hOut "bye\n"
repeatUntilExit hIn hOut f x = hGetChar hIn >>= \c -> f c >> repeatUntilExit hIn hOut f (appendToLastFive c)
  where appendToLastFive a = (reverse . (:)a . take 4 . reverse) x

forkFinally :: Exception e => IO a -> (Either e a -> IO ()) -> IO ThreadId
forkFinally action and_then =
  mask $ \restore ->
    forkIO $ try (restore action) >>= and_then
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type signature for [`forkFinally`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Control-Concurrent.html#v%3aforkFinally) in the latest Control.Concurrent:

```
forkFinally :: IO a -> (Either SomeException a -> IO ()) -> IO ThreadId
```

Type signature for `forkFinally` in your code:

```
forkFinally :: Exception e => IO a -> (Either e a -> IO ()) -> IO ThreadId
```

You have tried to generalise the exception type. This isn't a problem if the exception type can be deduced from `forkFinally`'s second parameter. But this is `forkFinally`'s second parameter:

```
exitPool p :: a' -> IO ()
```

The type checker tries to unify `Either e a -> IO ()` with `a' -> IO ()` and ends up not being able to deduce what `e` is.

General solution: specify an explicit type. e.g.

```
t <- forkFinally (echoHandler a) (exitPool p :: Either SomeException () -> IO ())
```

Better specific solution: restore the original type signature to `forkFinally`. It doesn't seem to make sense for it to only catch a limited set of exceptions.

Comment: Ah great point, thanks, I grabbed my type sig for it from GHCi's original guess, I should have just dug into the Control.Concurrent package's source instead

Comment: Total side note since you already read my code; any ideas why my mapM killThread would be locking?

Comment: My guess is that the target threads are running in constant space, thus not allocating any memory, thus not reaching a safe point, thus `killThread` blocks. (Read notes for `throwTo` beneath [`killThread`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Control-Concurrent.html#v%3akillThread).) But I don't count myself qualified to diagnose this after only a cursory look, so I advise asking in a new top-level question. (And even if I've diagnosed the problem correctly, I don't know how to go about fixing it.)

Comment: Scratch that; `repeatUntilExit` is clearly allocating memory. So I don't know.